# github repository as a git template directory

Tags: git, github

So to my understanding there is the possibility to initialize or clone a git repository via `git init --template=<template_dir>` or `git clone <repository> --template=<template_dir>`, which just copies everything in that given folder in the .git folder, which is useful for hooks, etc.

So I was wondering, is there any possibility to provide a github repository as the `template_dir`? The reason for that is, I want to set up git hooks for a multiple projects/team members as automatic and future proof as possible. The way I am doing it right now is having a `git_hooks` folder in the rep and symlink it manually, but i am looking for a way to remove that extra step and automate it a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't seem to be possible:

- All the tests in [`t0001-init.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/t/t0001-init.sh) are expecting a local path for template directory
- Nothing in [`builtin/init-db.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/init-db.c) shows that an url might work.

A commit like [0c0ead (git 1.6.2, February 2009)](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0c0ead7e79559013d6f9eea6f7e55d1845c11171) only mentions a local path.

#### Makefile: fix misdetection of relative pathnames

> The installation rules wanted to differentiate between a `template_dir` that is given as an absolute path (e.g. `/usr/share/git-core/templates`) and a relative one (e.g. `share/git-core/templates`)

Answer (score 1):

I just setup a git-template repository at my company. So far it just has a single prepare-commit-msg hook in the hooks directory which prepends branch names (tracker numbers in our case) to commit messages. The common workflow would be to first clone the git-template repo, or pull any recent changes, and then use the `--template` option to git init to re-initialize each developer's local repositories. So far it's been well received.