# Creating stash hooks in repositories

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, jira

How to setup stash hooks either on new/existing Repositories?

I need to create new Repository hence want to setup stash hooks scripts for it.
Plus is it possible to setup stash hooks for pre-existing Repository?

Comment: What do you mean by *stash hooks*, `.git/hooks/*` files or something else?

Comment: @torek:  i mean creating hook scripts for any repository, for ex - while committing any changes there should be specific format for it, etc.                                                                                   . git/hooks that folder is present by default, do i need to make changes there ??

Comment: You've tagged a bunch of different pieces of software, but if you want *Git* to run hooks at the time you run `git <something>`, those go in `.git/hooks/`, yes. Git's hooks are documented in [githooks](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks/).

Comment: Are you asking about how to have Stash, the product now called Bitbucket Server, run its own server-side hooks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest you can provide as a way to automatically setup hooks would be a "[template directory](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init#_template_directory)", that is a shared folder whose content is copied in a cloned/initialized Git repository.

That would work if all developers had access to the same common shared folder, but that would not work for common shared *network* resources, such as GitLab or GitHub.
For those remote repos hosting services, an alternative ([described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32876980/6309)) would be to:

- clone a template repo hosted on GitHub or GitLab
- then create your own repo with the `--template` parameter referring to the cloned template repo.

Comment: Thanks i referred to your links!